# react hooks issue when infinite paging filter applied

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have an infinite paging setup in a react redux project like this..

```
const ItemDashboard = () => {

  const items= useSelector(state => state.items.items);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [loadedItems, setLoadedItems] = useState([]);
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([
    'cycling',
    'diy',
    'electrical',
    'food',
    'motoring',
    'travel'
  ]);
  const initial = useRef(true);
  const [loadingInitial, setLoadingInitial] = useState(true);
  const [moreItems, setMoreItems] = useState([]);

  const onChangeFilter = (category, show) => {
    !show
      ? setCategories(categories.filter(c => c != category))
      : setCategories([...categories, category]);
  };

  const loadItems = () => {
     dispatch(getItems(categories, items && items[items.length - 1]))
        .then(more => setMoreItems(more));
  }

  const getNextItems = () => {
    loadItems();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if(initial.current) {
      loadItems();
      setLoadingInitial(false);
      initial.current = false;
    } 
  }, [loadItems]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(items) {
      setLoadedItems(loadedItems => [...loadedItems, ...items]);
    }
  }, [items]);

  useEffect(() => {
      //this effect is fired on intial load which is a problem!
      setLoadingInitial(true);
      initial.current = true;
  }, [categories]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Filter onFilter={onChangeFilter} categories={categories} />
      {loadingInitial ? (
        <Row>
          <Col sm={8} className='mt-2'>
            <LoadingComponent />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      ) : (
        <ItemList
          items={loadedItems}
          getNextItems={getNextItems}
          moreItems={moreItems}
        />
      )}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

In the filter component, when the filter is changed the onChangeFilter handler method is fired which updates the array of categories in state. When this filter is changed I need to set the loadedItems in state to an empty array and call the load items callback again but I can't work out how to do it. If I add another effect hook with a dependency on categories state, it fires on the initial load also. I'm probably doing this all wrong as it feels a bit hacky the whole thing. Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: post the error maybe ?

Comment: Can't you also set `loadedItems` inside `onChangeFilter()` and get rid of useEffect() that checks for `categories` changes?

Comment: Yes I could! If I set the loadedItems object to an empty array and then set the initial.current to true it will trigger a load from the effect that runs each time.. thanks.. still feels clunky but it works so...